# How to use a container as page indicator with color filling animation

Tags: flutter

[image: This image contain three page indicators, it is filled one by one base on changing the index.]
I am working with flutter. This image contain three page indicators, it is filled one by one base on changing the index. My requirement is to fill the indicator based on index , and when last one is go to first one and repeat the action.

Comment: can you share the code.

Comment: Please share the code you have tried. Otherwise, no one would waste time coding that for you from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

This package it does the job you want... Try it out
[step_progress_indicator](https://pub.dev/packages/step_progress_indicator)